# HTML5/JQuery mobile input type date , How to prevent future dates

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile in my Html5 application.I have created datepicker with input type date tag like :

```
 <input name="" id="mydate" placeholder="" value="" type="date"  data-mini="true">
```

Now I want to disable future dates. Please suggest me workaround for this.
Note :I cannot use JQueryUI in my project.So cant use JqueryUI datepicker.

Comment: set max attribute to current date

Comment: @Satpal: no its not working

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

You can use max property and set this value using js